# PHP - Returning all paragraphs up to first <h2>

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Wikipedia articles have this structure:

```
<div id="bodyContent"> 
  <div id="siteSub">...</div> 
  <div id="contentSub"></div> 
  <div id="jump-to-nav">...</div> 
  <table class="infobox vevent">...</table> 
  <p>Article summary</p>
  <p>Article summary continued</p>
  <p>Article summary continued</p>
  <table id="toc" class="toc">...</table> 

  <h2>...</h2> 
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I am interested in the summary part. With Xpath, I want to say:

**Return `<p>` nodes inside `#bodyContent` from the start AND stop as soon as you encounter the first `<h2>`**

How do I say this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like `//div[@id="bodyContent"]/h2[1]/preceding-sibling::p`.

This says "from `#bodyContent`'s children, find the first `h2` element and among its preceding siblings find all `p` elements".